# Starcraft starts with python-sc2 but nothing happens after the loading screen

Tags: python, runtime

As a learning exercise I have been trying to build a CNN to play Starcraft.
The below code is a sample of what I'm trying to run. However, when the game starts I can see the game window loading the map (which doesn't display the picture) but when it finishes loading the screen closes and nothing happens afterward.

Has someone experienced anything similar?

I'm using spyder with python 3.7.3 and sc2 0.11.1
I have followed the instructions on https://github.com/Dentosal/python-sc2 to the letter.

My system is:/n
Window 10 Pro 64bit
Intel i7-8700K CPI 6 core (12 logical processors) @ 3.7GHz
32GB RAM
NVIDA GeFORCE GTX 1080 GPU
C drive 326GB free of 464GB
D drive 931 GB

I can run the game by itself so I don't think this is hardware related.

```
import sc2

from sc2 import run_game, maps, Race, Difficulty
from sc2.player import Bot, Computer

class MyBot(sc2.BotAI):
    async def on_step(self, iteration):
        await self.distribute_workers()

run_game(maps.get('AbyssalReefLE'), [Bot(Race.Protoss, 
                                     MyBot()),
                                     Computer(Race.Terran, Difficulty.Easy)], 
        realtime = True)
```

I expect that the game opens and the probes start collecting resources.

However, when the code executes I get the following Runtime error:

```
File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 526, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

This is even after a reboot. If I try to run the code again I get the following:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_host_game() done, defined at C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\main.py:221> exception=ValueError('3794 is not a valid AbilityId')>
ValueError: 3794 is not a valid AbilityId

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\main.py", line 233, in _host_game
    result = await _play_game(players[0], client, realtime, portconfig, step_time_limit, game_time_limit, rgb_render_config)
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\main.py", line 204, in _play_game
    result = await _play_game_ai(client, player_id, player.ai, realtime, step_time_limit, game_time_limit)
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\main.py", line 91, in _play_game_ai
    game_data = await client.get_game_data()
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\client.py", line 143, in get_game_data
    return GameData(result.data)
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\game_data.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.abilities = {a.ability_id: AbilityData(self, a) for a in data.abilities if a.ability_id in ids}
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\game_data.py", line 29, in <dictcomp>
    self.abilities = {a.ability_id: AbilityData(self, a) for a in data.abilities if a.ability_id in ids}
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\game_data.py", line 94, in __init__
    assert self.id != 0
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\site-packages\sc2\game_data.py", line 102, in id
    return AbilityId(self._proto.remaps_to_ability_id)
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\enum.py", line 310, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\enum.py", line 564, in __new__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\enum.py", line 548, in __new__
    result = cls._missing_(value)
  File "C:\Users\wizha\Anaconda3\envs\starcraft\lib\enum.py", line 577, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 3794 is not a valid AbilityId
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed connection
client_connection: Connection<ConnectionKey(host='127.0.0.1', port=24418, is_ssl=False, ssl=None, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None, proxy_headers_hash=None)>
INFO:sc2.protocol:Client status changed to Status.launched (was None)
INFO:sc2.controller:Creating new game
INFO:sc2.controller:Map:     AbyssalReefLE
INFO:sc2.controller:Players: Bot(Race.Protoss, <__main__.DukeBot object at 0x0000021E27D7A860>), Computer(Race.Terran, Difficulty.Easy)
INFO:sc2.protocol:Client status changed to Status.init_game (was Status.launched)
INFO:sc2.protocol:Client status changed to Status.in_game (was None)
INFO:root:Player id: 1 (None)
INFO:sc2.sc2process:kill_switch: Process cleanup
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleaning up...
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleanup complete
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleaning up...
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleanup complete
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleaning up...
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleanup complete
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleaning up...
INFO:sc2.sc2process:Cleanup complete
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error, the game's current version is not compactible with the modul.
There is a thread about it: https://github.com/Dentosal/python-sc2/issues/283
There is also an instruction how to remove the error, it worked for me, so hope it will help you as well.